How to easily search in the recipient list in the Message window
Not in the main message list, but when a message is opened in its own window (in the desktop application), if there are many people in the recipient list, it's difficult to see if some particular recipient was included in the list.
Is there a way to search this list? (the Find option only searches inside the message body) besides copying the list into a text editor?
Or alternatively show those addresses in a list like Gmail does? (it's much easier to search visually in that way)

There is not a built-in mechanism for searching the address fields.  The easiest way that I've found is

Click in the address field (To:, From:, etc)
Press Ctrl-A to select all
Copy/paste into your favorite text editor with a Find feature

Doing this copies both display name and email address so both are searchable.
